# SanDisk SSD Extreme 500 not detected by macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, ntfs

I have an external SSD device which is randomly mounted in my MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra (anyway, I had this problem even in Yosemite, it is not OS related).

I've formatted the SSD with Disk Utility app to NTFS because I need a drive readable from wherever. I do have the Paragon NTFS for Mac app (version 14.3.318), so I guess the filesystem is not the issue. I said so also because this morning, just after the format, I was able to copy stuffs to the ext SSD. But right now is not detected at all.

If I run in the terminal:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

I can only see the internal SSD

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 536C2ECC-3939-4732-9357-2F037669B42F
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Capacity Ceiling (Size):      250790436864 B (250.8 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   165896990720 B (165.9 GB) (66.1% used)
    Capacity Available:           84893446144 B (84.9 GB) (33.9% free)
```

What is going on?
Thank you for any help you will provide

Comment: @klanomath sorry, not iOS expert, what if I'm running **High** Sierra? Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Done! **ProductName**: Mac OS X; **ProductVersion**:10.13.1. So I have High Sierra.. How is this related to my issue? I did have the same problem with Yosemite

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. The Paragon NTFS for Mac version is 14.3.318

Comment: Try to update to Paragon NTFS for Mac 15 - AFAIK the first version also supporting 10.13.

Comment: `diskutil apfs list` will only show volumes formatted as APFS, not your NTFS disk. run `diskutil list` instead.

Comment: @klanomath: Upgrading the Paragon app is the solution, thank you! Could you please post your comment as the answer? So I'll also flag it as solved.